Can I run a gate opener and cameras on this long cable?
I have a 1000' underground 10/3 cable for a gate opener system and cameras. On that continuous cable, at about every 300' the cable has a few feet above ground. The cable is on a 30 amp breaker. I wish to run the double gate opener system and a few cameras. What do I need at the end of the run to bring the 240v down to 110v and can I run both gate opener and cameras? I understand that there is a loss of power over this distance, is this why every 300' the cable is above ground for a breaker box?

A sub panel will separate 120 and 240.  Running the gate openers will depend on how many amps they need.  Having boxes every so often does not help with voltage loss.  Running larger gauge wire helps.

Are they breaker boxes at the intermediate points, or just junction boxes?

Also, how much power does this gate opener pull?

A voltage drop calculator shows only 165v at the end.  If the gate opener needs 240v, then do not expect them to last and to burn out soon.

What do you mean by "above ground?"

@crip659 What on earth are you using for a current value? 165V at the end of 1000' of #10 wire (starting from 240V) means a load of more than 30A (> 7200W). Gate openers take less than a tenth of that (possibly much less). Voltage drop shouldn't be much of an issue even at 120V (7.0% at 4A), and definitely not a problem if the load is 240V.

@nobody   Just the first online voltage drop calculator, using OPs specs.  10 gauge at just 300ft will just power lights.  Trying to use a motor did dim the lights at the same time.  15 amps circuit 120v.

@crip659 You have clearly done the calculation wrong. Voltage on 1000 feet of #10 doesn't drop down to 165V (from 240V source) unless the load is 36A. The resistance of #10 copper is 1.1417 Ohms per thousand feet. https://www.calculator.net/voltage-drop-calculator.html?necmaterial=copper&necwiresize=2&necconduit=pvc&necpf=0.85&material=copper&wiresize=0.4066&resistance=1.2&resistanceunit=okm&voltage=240&phase=ac&noofconductor=1&distance=1000&distanceunit=feet&amperes=36&x=Calculate&ctype=nec

Is this a two pole breaker (i.e. double wide), or just a single width breaker?  To (easily) come out with ~120V at the far end, you'll need to make sure that you have two hots on opposite phases, a neutral, and a ground.  If all you have is a single 30A breaker connected only to a single phase, then it gets much more complicated.

From the desire to get 110V on a 240V line I deduce you are in North America with a split-phase power system.
A #/3 cable (12/3, 10/3, 8/3, etc) can be run at 120V/240 down its length, if the cable is fed from a double breaker putting both legs of the split phase power on it, along with its neutral wire.
The pop-ups above ground every 300 feet may be more for future additions of electric boxes or lighting poles along its length. If the cable is in conduit, the pop-ups may have been to facilitate pulling the cable through the conduit. Popping the cable above ground will have no effect on preventing power loss over the long cable.
Note that if you do decide to put outlets at the intermediary popups, you will not be able to keep the 30 amp breaker. Regular NEMA 5 outlets are only 15 or 20 amps and are not allowed by code on a 30-amp breaker. You'd have to replace the breaker with a 20 amp and use 20-amp or 15-amp receptacles. You can continue to use a double breaker and feed the outlets in a multi-wire branch circuit arrangement, which could also allow 240V outlets along the path too.
Whether the gate opener can run at the end of this cable strongly depends on the current draw of the gate opener. If it draws only a few milliamps, there will be practically no voltage drop. If it draws multiple or tens of amps, voltage drop will be a serious problem, possibly preventing the gate from working well, a long time, or at all.
The cameras' power supplies likely draw very little current and will not contribute to voltage drop. However, if the voltage drop caused by a high-current gate is excessive it could drop voltage too much on the camera supplies and knock the cameras off-line when the gate attempts to open.
Frame challenge: Some gates run on a 12-volt deep cycle lead acid battery which gets recharged by a solar panel. This setup works because the high current draw of the gate feeds from the high-current-capable battery, and the gate isn't opening all the time, so the battery can recharge sufficiently.
If you don't plan to be opening/closing the gate dozens of times an hour all day long, you could consider a battery-powered gate, and run a trickle charger off the end of the long cable to charge the battery. The trickle charger won't draw much current, making the voltage drop negligible, and allowing the camera power supplies to remain working.
Trying to run high-current devices at outlets along the cable may be cause for excessive voltage drop, though. How much drop depends on how much current draw and how far along the cable.
An alternative idea if a high-current gate or lots of gate openings are required:
The solution to reducing voltage drop along a cable because of current draw is to increase cable voltage so current reduces. You could get 240-480V center-tapped transformers, one at each end of the long cable.
The cable would be at 480V (likely the cable is rated for 600V, but confirm this), so absolutely no outlets along the cable (mark those above-ground boxes DANGER 480V) though there are 480V outdoor lights available.
At the end of the cable, after the 480-240 transformer (in an outside-capable box), you'd need an outdoor split-phase circuit breaker panel, with the panel's neutral being fed by the transformer's 240V center tap. This panel would need the ground and neutral combined, because the transformer acts like a separate standalone service for its panel. You need ground rods and a continuous ground wire at this panel, too. Then feed the gate and cameras from the panel's breakers.
The doubling of the cable's voltage causes a halving of the cable's current, meaning 1/4 of the power loss that was happening before.

Great point about the solar powered gate operators using battery storage. Some of the mains-powered gate operators do the same -- I'm familiar with some of the GTO/Mighty Mule products, for example, and observed that these use a 30 watt "wall wart" power supply to maintain their 12 v battery.

Your cameras probably have external PSUs that accept 90 to 240V.  If they don't, replace the PSUs with ones that do that's done.  Also with 10/3 you have 120V down there and the cameras use so little power the voltage drop will be next to nothing.
The length of wire is a problem only if you pull a lot of current.  Newer gate actuators use may only use 30% the power of similar older ones, 500 or 600W or so.  At 240V that's 3A or less ... and with #10 wire you won't lose enough voltage to matter.  You'll be fine.  Just find a new, energy-efficient actuator that runs on 240V.  Look for features like a DC motor with slow start to avoid inrush current, and don't oversize it.  It will be fine at 240V.

AC or DC shouldn't affect power. If a 500W DC motor can operate a given gate, so can a 500W AC motor.

@nobody thanks, I changed that to be more clear about the point I am making.
